# Error: bad command `​nospoof on' in /etc/host.conf file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-17.04

Iam using a Ubuntu 17.10 VM in GCP. To prevent my server's IP from being spoofed, I did the below changes in my /etc/host.conf file:

Changed from:

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

To

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
​order bind,hosts
​nospoof on
```

But this gave the below error:

```
/etc/host.conf: line 2: bad command `​order bind,hosts'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `​nospoof on'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What produced the errors?

Comment: Modern systems use `/etc/nsswitch.conf` instead of `/etc/host.conf`

Comment: @jordanm Why then does the man page say: **hosts       Host names and numbers, used by gethostbyname(3) and related functions.** ? *`gethostbyname(3)`* is long obsoleted; POSIX.1-2001 and in POSIX.1-2008 it was marked to be removed. On my boxen (Fedora, CentOS) *`order`*, *`multi`* and *`reorder`* are still definitely not considered a bad command. So in 2017 your comment doesn't really make much sense to me. (Not that host.conf doesn't use those either, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those obsolete options you placed in `/etc/host.conf` have any effect anymore. And Google will prevent your IP from being spoofed; you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Is there any way to reset it because I get that error all the time.

Comment: Just put the original content back. Or an empty file. On my system it only says `multi on`.

Comment: There are similar discussions on this matter on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990078/what-measures-does-google-cloud-take-to-protect-the-instances-from-ip-spoofing) and [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/1yCdTamt4qs)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in other repos. I have delete those four repos:

- CentOS-Base.repo
- CentOS-CR.repo
- CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
- CentOS-fasttrack.repo

and it works